# rake db:create - Mysql2::Error: Unknown database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am trying to create a database using `rake db:create` task.

When I am running the command `bundle exec rake db:create` to create the database and load the schema, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Unknown database 'xxx_development'
```

My `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  reconnect: true
  username: user
  password: password
  pool: 50
  database: xxx_development
```

I checked that mysql server is running and I am able to connect to it using the password/username I have in the `database.yml`

I also understand that I can go ahead and create the database in `mysql` and then run the `bundle exec rake db:create` but isn't the rake task `db:create` also creates a database in case it doesn't exists?

The `rails` version is `3.2.22`.
and `mysql2` version is `2.9.13`.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ohmyzsh with bundler plugin which makes `rake` run by default with `bundle exec`, you can use

```
unbundled_rake db:create
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar issue on Rails 5 and the following steps helped me fix it:

```
Spring stop

./bin/rails db:create
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas.

1. Check the User permissions
2. When I run rake tasks, I don't use bundle exec (i.e just rake db:create)

Hope this is helpful

Comment: I have all the permissions for the mysql user but same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=development` hope this will work

Comment: @Undo thanks for the link. I see your point and have to apologise, I clearly misunderstood the concept. Will keep that in mind. Thanks again for pointing that out to me.

Comment: No problem @RenéVogt :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `rails db:create` failed but my workaround was

to create dbs directly in mysql

```
sudo mysql
create database myapp_development;
create database myapp_test;
```

After that run as normal

```
rake db:migrate db:seed
```